# Why is WebStorm file dialog box grey and inversed? (Occurs on MacOS, just after installing Elm)

Tags: macos, webstorm

I opened WebStorm to make a new project, and the file dialog box is now in reversed black and white (see image).  I tested out some other programs on my Mac and their dialog boxes seem normal -- that is, this would seem to be a WebStorm-only phenomenon  The only thing I did since the last time I used WebStorm was to install elm, elm-test and elm-format to my Mac just now -- the first using an installer, the second using npm.  Any idea what might be going on?  It's disconcerting.  [image]

Comment: You seem to have dark IDE theme. Maybe it tries to match it? Try switching to light theme and restart -- is it better now?

Comment: Yes indeedy, that seems to have been it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Dark custom theme was enabled.  Doh!